# Disabling Firebase Offline Capabilities on Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, caching, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase Database, but I am aware of Java as a developer. I just want to disable the Firebase database to fetch data when my app has not **Active Internet Connection**.

---

My Application Class is:

```
public class MApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FireBaseConnectionClass.setFirebaseDataBaseConnection();
    }
}
```

---

and FireBaseConnectionClass class is:

```
public class FireBaseConnectionClass {
    private static FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = null;

    public static void setFirebaseDataBaseConnection() {
        MyMLogger.showMLog("version", "setting FB Connection:::", "indexactivity", "checkappversion");
        if (firebaseDatabase == null) {
            MyMLogger.showMLog("version", "connection was:::" + "null", "indexactivity", "checkappversion");
            firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            firebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(false);
        }//if ends
    }

    public static FirebaseDatabase getFirebaseDatabaseConnection() {
        if (firebaseDatabase == null) {
            setFirebaseDataBaseConnection();
        }
        return firebaseDatabase;
    }

    public static void onLineDataBase() {
        if (firebaseDatabase != null) {
            firebaseDatabase.goOnline();
        }
    }

    public static void offLineDataBase() {
        if (firebaseDatabase != null) {
            firebaseDatabase.goOffline();
        }
    }
}
```

---

I am just getting the app version from my database in my Activity that comes after the splash screen activity!

```
private void checkAppVersion() {
        try {
            //activity not running return
            if (IndexActivity.this.isFinishing()) {
                return;
            }

            //get the database instance
            FireBaseConnectionClass.getFirebaseDatabaseConnection().getReference("app_version").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    //check if data snapshot exists
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        appVersionFromDatabase = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                        MyMLogger.showMLog("version", "version:::" + appVersionFromDatabase, "indexactivity", "checkappversion");
                    } else {
                        MyMLogger.showMLog("version", "snapshot not exists", "indexactivity", "checkappversion");
                        FireBaseConnectionClass.offLineDataBase();
                    }// if (dataSnapshot.exists())  ends
                }//onDataChange ends

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    MyMLogger.showMLog("version", "error:::" + databaseError.toString(), "indexactivity", "checkappversion");
                    FireBaseConnectionClass.offLineDataBase();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            MyMLogger.showMLog("version", "exception:::" + exp.toString(), "indexactivity", "checkappversion");
        }

    }
```

---

The main problem is that when I turned off the internet, the checkAppVersion() method gives the app version(may be from the cache!) that I don't want this!
I have also followed the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities).
Can somebody please tell me why this behavior is not happening to me, as I only want the app version when I have active Internet Connection!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Are you somehow using in your code `firebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(true);`?

Comment: i am using firebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(false);